# Security of key schedule that only XORs a key with constants

Tags: key-schedule

Suppose that:

- $MK \in \{0, 1\}^{n}$ and the main key of a block cipher.
- $RK_{r} \in \{0, 1\}^{n}$ and is the $r$<sup>th</sup> round key.
- $RC_{r} \in \{0, 1\}^{n}$ and is the $r$<sup>th</sup> round constant.
- $RK_{r} = MK \oplus RC_{r}$

What's the security of this key schedule. I'm imagining that it is not very strong.

Comment: "security" in regards to what? You might be interested in the [LED](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/600.pdf) cipher

Comment: This makes no sense.

Comment: Perhaps for the last line, you meant $RK_r = MK \oplus RC_r$?

Comment: In any case, unless the key schedule does something exceedingly silly (e.g. set all round keys to constant values), it's impossible to talk about the security of a key schedule without specifying what cipher it is a part of.  The above key schedule might cause the cipher to be quite weak; or it might be exactly the sort of thing the cipher needs to be secure.

Comment: A key schedule has no security definition. Also, how is this used in a cipher, what are the definitions, etc.? From the little information there, I would say this is vulnerable to linear and differential cryptanalysis at least.

Comment: @poncho I fixed it. How are they set to constants?

Comment: In your case, they're not constants.  My statement really is "there isn't much a key schedule can do that would always harm security"; the caveat of "unless the key schedule does something does something silly" was to forestall objections that there are things a horrid key schedule could do, not that you schedule does that...

Comment: Doesn't TEA use this technique for its key schedule?

Answer (score 4):

This key schedule is **Totally Linear**. If two Master Keys $MK$<sub>1</sub> and $MK$<sub>2</sub> have a difference of **d**, all the round keys will have difference of **d** with **probability of 1**. This makes the cipher vulnerable to [Related key Attack](https://www.schneier.com/academic/paperfiles/paper-relatedkey.pdf). But its hard to workout and comment without the knowledge of the cipher description that **how badly such key-schedule effects the security of cipher**

The [PRINCE – A Low-latency Block Cipher for Pervasive Computing Applications](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/529.pdf) have very simple key-schedule, and its designers say

> for our cipher it holds that decryption for one key corresponds to
>   encryption with a related  key.  This  property  we  refer  to  as
>   α-reflection

For more information about key-schedule requirements see "[What are the requirements of a key schedule?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33975/what-are-the-requirements-of-a-key-schedule/34255)"

Comment: "This makes the cipher vulnerable to Related key Attack"; only if the rest of the cipher structure has issues with related round keys (and hence there might not be any such vulnerability at all...)

Comment: so its hard to workout or comment without the knowledge of cipher description that  how badly such key-schedule effects the security of cipher :)

Answer (score 2):

The addition of round constants in key-scheduling is to remove self-simlarity. Related key attack (is not practical attack in real life other than academia) will remove the effect of round constants in the analysis ( both keys are xored with the same round constant).

Invariant subspace a attack exploits the weakness of constant addition to the master key. this is what happens in Midori cipher, a class of weak keys found by this  approach.

it is important to choose round constant carefully to provide secure key scheduling of key and round constant.

For more details , I recommend to read the paper [Proving Resistance against Invariant Attacks: How to Choose the Round Constants](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/463.pdf)