# AES key schedule. Does it use a KDF to generate the round keys?

Tags: aes, key-derivation, key-schedule

So for each round in AES a different key is used, and as I saw the keys are created form a master key.

My question is how these round keys are generated.

**Are they created via a Key Derivation Function as the session keys, or its something else ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it uses a specific type of algorithm called a [*key schedule*](https://www.samiam.org/key-schedule.html). Unlike a KDF, it is not designed to be slow (in the case of a password-based KDF) or to be irreversible. The [requirements of a key schedule](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/33975/54184) are quite simple. Whereas a KDF might need to expand a key into a number of keys such that knowledge of any one key does not reveal knowledge of the master key or any other derived keys, that is not always true for a key schedule. If you have *any* round key for 128-bit AES, you can derive all other round keys.

Comment: Note that only password based key derivation functions are slow. Normally a key based key derivation function would be used for key expansion and those are fast. So the speed argument is invalid if you ask me.