# AES with a longer key instead of key expansion?

Tags: aes, password-hashing

What are the disadvantages of using AES-256 with 240-byte key (which scrypt/bcrypt/argon2/pbkdf2 can easily output) instead of an expanded 256-bit key?

The only disadvantage I can think of is "no more hardware acceleration". This is not important for a fair comparison, are there other disadvantages?

EDIT: This is about replacing round keys.

Comment: You cannot use a 240 byte key with AES. Key sizes are fixed to 128, 192, and 256 bits (16, 24, 32 bytes respectively). If you use a key derivation function, its output must either be the desired length or it must be truncated.

Comment: @Marc I mean separating an 240-byte key to arrays of 16-bytes and using a different array of 16-bytes in every round instead of KeyExpansion output of an 256 bit key.

Comment: Gotcha. You want to replace the AES key schedule with an existing KDF. Performance aside, this might mitigate some of the attacks due to the weak key schedule but I don't think those are so impressive to begin with.

Comment: [AES key schedule. Does it use a KDF to generate the round keys?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/72133/aes-key-schedule-does-it-use-a-kdf-to-generate-the-round-keys/72135?r=SearchResults&s=3|30.0221#72135)

Comment: @Marc @ kelalaka thanks my question is now answered.